# Python Pandas Groupby Multiple Level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

| day | category | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 5 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 2 |
| 2021-01-02 | B | 3 |
| 2021-01-03 | A | 4 |
| 2021-01-03 | B | 1 |
| 2021-01-04 | A | 3 |
| 2021-01-04 | B | 5 |

and I want to get something like this

| day | category | sales | sales_ix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 1 | 0.40 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 5 | 1.43 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 2 | 0.80 |
| 2021-01-02 | B | 3 | 0.86 |
| 2021-01-03 | A | 4 | 1.60 |
| 2021-01-03 | B | 1 | 0.29 |
| 2021-01-04 | A | 3 | 1.20 |
| 2021-01-04 | B | 5 | 1.43 |

The last column is daily sales divided by average daily sales by category (avg sales for A = 2.5 & b = 3.5).

I have tried

```
df['sales_ix'] = df['sales'].apply(lambda x: x/df.groupby('category').mean()['sales'])
```

,but it didn't work.

Does anybody know how to add the last column to df?

Comment: you need `.transform` but i don't think your calculations are correct avg daily sales for `2021-01-01` is `3` and avg sales for the same date for cat `A` is `1`  so avg sales by day & cat div avg sales by day is `0.3` I think the following works `df.groupby(['category','day'])['sales'].transform('mean').div(df.groupby('day')['sales'].transform('mean'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['sales_ix'] = df.groupby('category')['sales'].transform(lambda x: x.div(x.mean()))
```

Comment: This is neat but isn't quite what the question asks: you compute averages for (category, day) not for (category). This therefore produces different numbers to what we see in the desired output df in the question

Answer (score 0):

Example dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'day': list('12341234'),
  'category': list('aaaabbbb'),
  'sales':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
})
```

In order for the result of the aggregation to be compatible with the dataframe, you need to set the right index:

```py
df = df.set_index(['category'])
```

Now we can add the category average to the dataframe:

```py
df['category_mean'] = df.groupby(['category'])['sales'].mean()
```

Finally, we compute our target column:

```py
df['sales_ix'] = df['sales'] / df['category_mean']
```

Optionally, bring the `category` column back from the index:

```py
df.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `groupby` - `transform`:

```
result = (
    df.assign(
        sales_ix=df.groupby('category')['sales']
        .transform(lambda x: x / x.mean())
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

if there's just two categories you can use np.where

you could get the means of the categories beforehand, but you could also do it in a one-liner like this

```
df['sales_ix'] = np.where(
    df['category'] == 'A',
    df['sales'] / df[df['category'] == 'A']['sales'].mean(),
    df['sales'] / df[df['category'] == 'B']['sales'].mean()
)
```

Comment: Hardly readable, nothing is gained by this loss of generality